why is the extension group between a skyscraper sheaf and a torsionfree sheaf is zero
Let $X$ be a scheme, $\mathcal{F}_p$ be a skyscraper sheaf, and $\mathcal{G}$ be a torsionfree sheaf (or a vector bundle). Then I'd like to ask why every sequence of sheaves $0\to\mathcal{F}_p\to\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{G}\to0$ is split.
I have seen this question, but I don't understand the answer, could someone gives a direct proof for the splitness of the above sequence?

The answer to the linked question is saying that the sequence does not split in general.
